# How to autodefine elements from a list in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, assign

I want to create a list of both strings and integers, and make the strings work as variables whose value is the integers number.

```
list = ("y","1","x","3")
str(list[0]) == int(list[1])
str(list[2]) == int(list[3])

z = x + y
print(z)
```

I tried this, but it does't work anyway. Anybody knows a possible solution for that?

Comment: It's unclear what you are ultimately trying to do, but maybe you should look into SymPy?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
data = {"y": 1, "x": 3}

z = data["y"] + data["x"]

print(z) # 4
```

Also:

```
list = ("x", "1", "y", "3")
```

Does not create a list, that creates a `tuple`. Also, don't use names like `list` as it is using the same name as the built-in `list`.

Comment: +1 but why using dict.get instead of getitem access?  This will just turn a useful `KeyError` into a less-useful `TypeError`

Comment: @wim you're right. I get used to always using `.get` with a dictionary. For this example, accessing via `[]` would suffice. I've edited it out.

Comment: I thought about that, but what I'm trying to do is get the first from an input  and a dictionary is not a very useful version. I'll explain the real purpose: when the user writes an input like "y=3,x=2". Then I split up the parts and make an operation like (z = 2x - y) and print the solution. The problem is that idk how to do it...

Comment: Why would you want your user to enter this: "y=3,x=2"? You are over-complicating things. Why not ask the user for their value for x and value for y?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: exec 'y=1+1'

In [2]: y
Out[2]: 2
```

Needless to say that a dictionary is *way* better and that you should **not** trust user-provided input, personally I highly discourage you to pursue this path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` function to get the pairs and then use `exec()` to assign the integers to names:

```
>>> items = ("y","1","x","3")
>>> for i,j in zip(items[0::2], items[1::2]):
...     exec("{}={}".format(i,j))
... 
>>> x+y
4
```

But note that you need to be sure about the identity of your items, because using `exec()` might harm your machine.

Or as a more pythonic approach you can use a dict:

```
>>> items = ("y","1","x","3")
>>> the_dict = {i:int(j) for i, j in zip(items[0::2], items[1::2])}
>>> 
>>> the_dict['x'] + the_dict['y'] 
4
```

Again in this case you need be sure of the type of items because converting the digits might raise an exception if they are not valid digits.